# How to add/exclude fields to a form that extends another form

Tags: django

Example forms.py:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'role', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')

class AnotherUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    #???
```

Example models.py:

```
ROLE = [
    ("NU", "Normal User"),
    ("AU", "Abnormal User"),
]

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=50, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=50, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True)
    role = models.CharField(_('role'), max_length=2,
                            choices=ROLE, blank=True)
```

So I want to add `date_of_birth` to `AnotherUserCreationForm` and at the same time, I want to exclude `role` and `is_staff` in `AnotherUserCreationForm`. How do I manipulate it? Will it be done in the `Meta` class or do i manipulate it in the `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` of `AnotherUserCreationForm`?

Comment: You can define a `Meta` for `AnotherUserCreationForm` with different fields. Anyway there appears to be nothing in `UserCreationForm` worth inheriting? Or perhaps you just truncate that for the question?

Comment: Ye that's just for the sake of an example. So should I simply just redefine the fields in the `Meta` class once again?

Comment: Yes simply write a `Meta` class for `AnotherUserCreationForm`, it can inherit from `AnotherUserCreationForm.Meta` if there are more things there that you might want to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Meta` class of the `ModelForm` while making forms can be treated as a normal attribute of the form. And it similarly will follow the normal inheritance behavior if you set the attribute in the subclass, i.e. it will override / replace the one from the parent class. Since `Meta` is a class it can also inherit from the parent classes `Meta` if you want to keep some things from there, so you can do as follows:

```
class AnotherUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth')
```